# VBA Pie Chart Legend - How to set legend text?

Tags: excel, vba

A similar question was asked ([Set Legend Text Pie Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005023/set-legend-text-pie-chart)) but the solution doesn't work for me, maybe I'm missing something. I'm fairly new to working with VBA/Excel/Access and reports and I'm on a limited deadline so I am hoping somebody can enlighten me.

What I am doing is populating a range of cells with values pulled from an access database and then programatically generating pie charts based on these cell values. The pie charts are fairly simple and contain 2 pieces of data. I am generating 1-4 of them based on the users' selections. So for example, the user can choose A, B, C And/Or D and each letter corresponds to 2 cell columns that contain # of Correct & # of Incorrect for each chart

The reports are being generated inside of a loop (1 to 4) corresponding to A/B/C/D
The Code I'm using to create the charts looks like this:

```
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(20,shift(shiftIndex)), Cells(21, shift(shiftIndex))
ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
```

Which is saying to use the range B20:B21, C20:C21, etc for the Correct/Incorrect values. The problem is that the legend is showing "1" & "2" as labels and I want it to show "Correct" & "Incorrect"

In the other question, the person suggested using the syntax:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b6:c6," & "b" & x & ":c" & x)
```

Where b6 would contain "Correct" and c6 would contain "Incorrect" in my case for my labels but when I use this:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("a26:a27, a20:a21")
```

Where a26 contains "Correct", a27 contains "Incorrect" and a20 & a21 contain my correct and incorrect values - it tries to use all 4 values in my pie chart. Am I missing something here? Separating the parameters by a comma should indicate the first range as my legend and the second as my data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can directly control this using the XValues property of the Series object...

Assuming you have only one series in the chart try:

```
Activechart.Seriescollection(1).XValues=Activesheet.Range("a26:a27")
```

a further tip would be to do this:

```
Dim chMyChart as Chart 
Dim chMySeries as Series

Set chMyChart = Activesheet.Activechart 
Set chMySeries = chMyChart.Seriescollection(1)
```

and then use `chMyChart` in place of Active chart and `chMySeries` in place of `ActiveChart` etc.

This is more efficient, but it also activates vba's *Intellisense* that shows you a list of all of the properties available for these objects after you enter the ".".
For me anyway, this doesn't seem to be exposed on objects like `Active???` or indexed objects like `chMyChart.SeriesCollection(1)`